# DynamicJasper addColumn to fastreportbuilder with non-supported data type

Tags: java, reporting, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I have a list of objects that I am building a report for.  One of the attributes of the object is a JodaTime LocalDate object.  I would like this date to be included in my report, so I do something like:

```
.addColumn("Shipout", "shipout", LocalDate.class.getName(),50)
```

which results in the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
    1. Class "org.joda.time.LocalDate" not supported for text field expression.
```

That's fine, but there must be some way that I can add a LocalDate column type - I haven't been able to find anything like this in the documentation.

The closest thing I can find is a CustomExpression, but all of the examples refer to doing things like composite columns.

What is the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JasperReports version 3.7.1 (supported by DynamicJasper version 3.1.9) supports only this classes for text field's expression:

- java.lang.Boolean
- java.lang.Byte
- java.util.Date
- java.sql.Timestamp
- java.sql.Time
- java.lang.Double
- java.lang.Float
- java.lang.Integer
- java.lang.Long
- java.lang.Short
- java.math.BigDecimal
- java.lang.Number
- java.lang.String

You can make sure this fact looking at source code of this method from [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRVerifier](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/class-use/JRVerifier.html) class:

```
private static synchronized String[] getTextFieldClassNames()
{
    if (textFieldClassNames == null)
    {
        textFieldClassNames = new String[]
        {
            java.lang.Boolean.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Byte.class.getName(),
            java.util.Date.class.getName(),
            java.sql.Timestamp.class.getName(),
            java.sql.Time.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Double.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Float.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Integer.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Long.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Short.class.getName(),
            java.math.BigDecimal.class.getName(),
            java.lang.Number.class.getName(),
            java.lang.String.class.getName()
        };

        Arrays.sort(textFieldClassNames);
    }

    return textFieldClassNames;
}

private void verifyTextField(JRTextField textField)
{
    verifyReportElement(textField);
    verifyFont(textField);
    verifyAnchor(textField);
    verifyHyperlink(textField);

    if (textField != null)
    {
        JRExpression expression = textField.getExpression();

        if (expression != null)
        {
            try
            {
                String className = expression.getValueClassName();
                if (className == null)
                {
                    addBrokenRule("Class not set for text field expression.", expression);
                }
                else if (Arrays.binarySearch(getTextFieldClassNames(), className) < 0)
                {
                    addBrokenRule("Class \"" + className + "\" not supported for text field expression.", expression);
                }
            }
            catch (JRRuntimeException e)
            {
                addBrokenRule(e, expression);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the ***`verifyTextField`*** method generates this message in your case.

The full stack trace:

> 1. Class "org.joda.time.LocalDate" not supported for text field expression. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException:
>      Report design not valid :
> 2. Class "org.joda.time.LocalDate" not supported for text field expression.    at
>      net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:258)
>      at
>      net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:140)
>      at
>      net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)
>      at
>      ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:542)
>      at
>      ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:518)
>      at
>      ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJRXML(DynamicJasperHelper.java:403)

I think you should try to use scriptlet. Here is the [sample](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/groups/SystemVariableReportTest.html).

Comment: I'm not very impressed with this aspect of DynamicJasper, but I appreciate you bothering to dig your feet into the code base to find this.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a function e.g. `getLocalDateAsString` and implement this function with a return value of String in the POJO or ValueObject.

For example, In the Layouter

```
drb.addColumn("LocalType", "localTypeAsString", String.class.getName(), 50)
```

In the Entity:

```
public String getLocalTypeAsString() {
        String ret = null;
        if (mannschaftsTyp!=null) {
            ret = localType.getShortDescr();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

DJ cannot support what JR doesn't give. But you can create a CustomEpression Or ValueFormatter and convert the data as you need. You only need a few lines.
Because the type is unsupported, declare its type as object, then in the custom expression or value formatter downcast and operate as necessary

See http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-value-formatter/